# mysql 5.6 round datetime to nearest minute

Tags: mysql, datetime, rounding

I am trying to round a millisecond precision DATETIME, i.e. DATETIME(3) to the nearest minute. For example:

```
2020-07-27 17:33:59.954 => 2020-07-27 17:34:00.000
2020-07-27 17:42:58.799 => 2020-07-27 17:42:59.000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> select now(3), from_unixtime(floor((unix_timestamp(now(3))+30)/60)*60) as nearest_minute;
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| now(3)                  | nearest_minute      |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-07-31 18:46:22.518 | 2020-07-31 18:46:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [CAST it as DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`dt` datetime(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`dt`)
> VALUES
>     ('2020-07-27 17:33:59.954'),
>     ('2020-07-27 17:42:58.799')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `dt` ,CAST(`dt` AS DATETIME)  FROM Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                         | CAST(`dt` AS DATETIME)
> :------------------------- | :---------------------
> 2020-07-27 17:33:59.954000 | 2020-07-27 17:34:00   
> 2020-07-27 17:42:58.799000 | 2020-07-27 17:42:59
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca801d855695f5e103a8b72f08fcec3d)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rather unsatisfying solution I came up with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION timestamp_to_nearest_minute (t DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 
    CASE 
    WHEN CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM t) AS DECIMAL(11,3)) / 1000.0 < 500
        THEN 
            DATE_SUB(t, INTERVAL CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM t) AS DECIMAL(11,3)) MICROSECOND)
        ELSE
            DATE_ADD(t, INTERVAL 1000000.0 - CAST(EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM t) AS DECIMAL(11,3)) MICROSECOND)
    END
;
```